# Get enum value by name stored in a string in PHP

Tags: php, enums

I want to get the value of an Enum in PHP by its name.
My enum is like:

```
enum Status : int
{
    case ACTIVE = 1;
    case REVIEWED = 2;
    // ...
}
```

`Status::from(2)` can be used to get `"REVIEWED"`, but how can I resolve the value from the name stored in a string ?

Comment: suggested [reading](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.enumerations.backed.php)

Comment: Is it not simply echo `Status::REVIEWED`? - Sorry new to PHP Enums...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well, it seems there is not any built-in solution in PHP. I've solve this with a custom function:

```
enum Status : int
{
    case ACTIVE = 1;
    case REVIEWED = 2;
    // ...

    public static function fromName(string $name): string
    {
        foreach (self::cases() as $status) {
            if( $name === $status->name ){
                return $status->value;
            }
        }
        throw new \ValueError("$name is not a valid backing value for enum " . self::class );
    }

}
```

Then, I simply use `Status::fromName('ACTIVE')` and get `1`

If you want to mimic the `from` and `tryFrom` enum functions, you can also add:

```
public static function tryFromName(string $name): string|null
{
    try {
        return self::fromName($name);
    } catch (\ValueError $error) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: keep in mind that `from` returns `self`, this function return `string`.

Comment: I'm confused why this is returning a string. It's turning a string into a string? Shouldn't it be returning a self somehow?

Answer (score 12):

The [constant()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) function can return the value of a constant using a string variable.

This also applies to Enum class constants as mentioned in the [basic enumeration section](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.enumerations.basics.php#127112) of the PHP Manual.

```php
$name = 'REVIEWED';
$status = constant("Status::{$name}");
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer!

Comment: As the name of the enumeration is included in a string, this won't work well with many IDEs when you want to find all the places the quoted enumeration is used, or if you want to refactor the name of the enumeration.

Answer (score 8):

#### Update for PHP8.3:

```
$name = 'REVIEWED';
Status::{$name}->value;
Status::{'REVIEWED')->value;
```

https://php.watch/versions/8.3/dynamic-class-const-enum-member-syntax-support

#### Previously:

You can use reflection for Backed case:

```
$reflection = new ReflectionEnumBackedCase(Status::class, 'REVIEWED');
$reflection->getBackingValue(); // 2
$reflection->getValue() // Status::REVIEWED if you need case object
```

Or enum reflection:

```
$reflection = new ReflectionEnum(Status::class);
$reflection->getCase('REVIEWED')->getValue()->value // 2
```

see also ReflectionEnumUnitCase

Comment: Reflection reduce performance of api

Comment: @Mitsukk I wonder where this belief comes from. Unless you mean PHP4 or less. In this particular case, Reflection is faster than the loop from the accepted answer, and the difference increases as the number of cases increases. Besides, performance was not mentioned in this question.

Comment: Thank's @fela, can you give me documentation about this please?
My manager told me that, I want to have argument for discuss with him

Answer (score 3):

I use a custom method too, but I return an enum.
The *from* method returns an enum, not a value. I think the *fromName* method should return an enum too. Then you have access to all methods of the enum. You don't need use another method - *from*.

```
public static function fromName(string $name): self
{
    foreach (self::cases() as $status) {
        if( $name === $status->name ){
            return $status;
        }
    }
    throw new \ValueError("$name is not a valid backing value for enum " . self::class );
}

public static function tryFromName(string $name): self|null
{
    try {
        return self::fromName($name);
    } catch (\ValueError $error) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone cares, I have created a library around that.

https://github.com/henzeb/enumhancer

Just add the trait to your enum

```
enum Status : int
{
    use Henzeb\Enumhancer\Enhancers;
    
    case ACTIVE = 1;
    case REVIEWED = 2;
    // ...
}

Status::get('ACTIVE');
Status::tryGet('ACTIVE');
```

You then don't have to use values at all. In that case you can also simply use from.

```
enum Status
{
    use Henzeb\Enumhancer\Enhancers;
    
    case ACTIVE;
    case REVIEWED;
    // ...
}

Status::from('ACTIVE')->key(); // returns 0
Status::tryFrom('Reviewed')->key(); // returns 1
```

It does so much more than that, but it defeats copying and pasting snippets around.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `tryFrom` or `from`:

#### Example of enum:

```php
enum Fruits: string
{
    case APPLE = 'Apple';
    case PEAR = 'Pear';
    case ORANGE = 'Orange';

    public function getDescription(): string
    {
        return match ($this) {
            Fruits::APPLE => 'X',
            Fruits::PEAR => 'Y',
            Fruits::ORANGE => 'Z',
        };
    }

}
```

### `tryFrom`: Get Enum instance or null from string

###### *Maps a scalar to an enum instance or null*

```php
$stringValue = 'Pear';

$fruit = Fruits::tryFrom($stringValue);

if ($fruit !== null) {
   echo $fruit->getDescription(); // "Y"
   echo $fruit->value; // "Pear"
}
```

**Documentation:** https://www.php.net/manual/en/backedenum.tryfrom.php

### `from`: Get Enum instance or ValueError from string

###### *Maps a scalar to an enum instance or throw a `ValueError` exception*

```php
$stringValue = 'Pear';

try { 
   $fruit = Fruits::from($stringValue);

   echo $fruit->getDescription(); // "Y"
   echo $fruit->value; // "Pear"
} catch (\ValueError $exception) { 
   echo $exception->getMessage(); // Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: "Tree" is not a valid backing value for enum "Fruit"
}
```

**Documentation:** https://www.php.net/manual/en/backedenum.from.php

Comment: Since PHP 8.1.0 this is how it should be done.

Comment: This is incorrect, you haven't read the question properly.

They are trying to get the Enum from the string value of the case name.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the constant() function to get the Enum, then get the value from that. And personally, I would use a trait so you don't have to create the function for every enum you want this feature for:

```php
trait EnumFromName
{
    public static function valueFromName(string $name): self
    {
        return constant("self::$name");
    }
}
```

Enum class:

```php
enum Status : int
{
    use EnumFromName;

    case ACTIVE = 1;
    case REVIEWED = 2;
    // ...
}
```

Calling:

```php
Status::valueFromName('REVIEWED')->value;
```

Answer (score 1):

To get value from the name:

```
enum Status : int
{
   case ACTIVE = 1;
   case REVIEWED = 2;
   // ...
}

print(Status::REVIEWED->value);
```

[Enum documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.enumerations.backed.php)

Comment: I have the name in a string, I edited my question to be more specific. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did - https://3v4l.org/8R2fP#v8.2.10:

```php
<?php

enum Gender
{
    case UNKNOWN;
    case MALE;
    case FEMALE;
}

/**
 * @template T as BackedEnum|UnitEnum
 * @param class-string<T> $enumClass
 * @param string $name
 * @return T|null
 */
function tryFromName(string $enumClass, string $name)
{
    $constName = $enumClass . '::' . $name;

    return is_subclass_of($enumClass, UnitEnum::class) && defined($constName)
        ? constant($constName)
        : null;
}

// enum(Gender::UNKNOWN)
var_dump(tryFromName(Gender::class, 'UNKNOWN'));

// enum(Gender::MALE)
var_dump(tryFromName(Gender::class, 'MALE'));

// enum(Gender::FEMALE)
var_dump(tryFromName(Gender::class, 'FEMALE'));

// NULL
var_dump(tryFromName(Gender::class, 'null'));
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.